# printf right align a bracketed number

Tags: c, format, printf

I'm writing a program that displays all the info in an array. It has to start with the array index in brackets (e.g. `[2]`) and they have to be right aligned with each other.

if it was just the number, I know that you can do:

```
printf("%-10d", index);
```

but putting brackets around that would give the following output

```
[         1]
[         2]
...
[        10]
[        11]
```

when I really want it to be:

```
         [1]
         [2]
...
        [10]
        [11]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it in two steps: first build a non-aligned string in a temporary buffer, then print the string right-aligned.

```
char buf[sizeof(index) * (CHAR_BITS + 2) / 3 + 4];
sprintf(buf, "[%d]", index);
printf("%-12s", buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

One easy thing to do would be to break it down to a two step process:

```
char tmp[128];
sprintf(tmp, "[%d]", index);
printf("%-10s", tmp);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need only one line and **no** temporary char-buffer:

```
printf("%*s[%d]\n",12-(int)log10(index),"",index);
```

Comment: It wasn't stated as a requirement, but this only works if index > 0.

Comment: Yeah, premature optimization and over-engineering all the way down, making your code impossible to debug or maintain 6 months from now. ;-)