# How do I make a printf statement only be so long?

Tags: c, format, printf

For instance:

```
Address            Numbers
[   0] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[ 981] 1 4 3 9 0 1 9 2 8
[  45] 0 3 3 3 4 1 2 3 0
[1512] 8 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 9
```

I know I could do something to check how long the character is and then do a %*s tag to add x amount of spaces, but is there a short and not messy way to define a printf segment to only be so long?

EDIT:

Okay, sorry for the confusion.

So heres what happens right now...

```
Address            Numbers
[   0] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[   981] 1 4 3 9 0 1 9 2 8
[   45] 0 3 3 3 4 1 2 3 0
[   1512] 8 2 1 2 3 1 1 1 9
```

I'm trying to get it to match the top part though

Comment: How are you outputting this data right now?  Show us some code.

Comment: Am I correct that you aren't happy with the placement of "Numbers"?

Comment: Also, '%50s' still overflows if the string is longer, I believe. Can this be forced to truncate?

Comment: Using `%4d` should line up the numbers, as long as all the numbers are <= 9999.

Comment: A quick Google search on `printf documentation` turned up http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output in the third result.

Answer (score 3):

As I have found in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12253400/897968) here, you could use this to right-align your numbers:

```
printf("[%4d]", number);
```

Apart from that, I don't quite understand what you meant by "only be so long"?